# VB.NET - Public Shared Function

Tags: sql, vb.net

Tenho uma função em um sistema VB.NET que utilizo para executar queries no BD.
A função é do tipo Public Shared por uma questão de simplicidade.
E há a dúvida se acessos concorrentes à função poderiam gerar problemas.

Isto é usuário 'A' chama a função com uma query e antes da consulta ser executada, usuário 'B' chama a mesma função com uma query diferente. Assim esse acesso concorrente pode gerar resultados inesperados?

Abaixo o código:

```
Public Class ExecuteDB
    Public Shared Function Execute(ByVal query As String) As DataSet
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        If query Is Nothing OrElse query = "" Then
            Return ds
        End If

        Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CnString").ConnectionString

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            Try
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                da.Fill(ds)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Using

        Return ds
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez eu não tenha compreendido bem a pergunta, no meu entendimento você está confundindo o modificado de acesso `Public Shared` com concorrência do BD. Caso seja isso, eles não tem relacionamento.

Com relação ao acesso concorrente a execução da `query` esse sim pode gerar resultados inesperados, veja o exemplo clássico do depósito bancário.

Imagine que uma conta não possa ficar com saldo negativo e a seguinte operação é executada:

```
    var umaConta = new ContaConjunta();
    //UsuarioA R$1000,00
    umaConta.depositar(1000.0, "UsuarioA"); //Local A
    umaConta.getSaldo();
    umaConta.sacar(1000,"UsuarioA");

   // Usuario B Saque R$300,00 desta conta  //Local B
    umaConta.getSaldo();
    umaConta.sacar(300,00,"UsuarioB");
```

Sem um controle de concorrência, um atraso na operação de saque do `UsuarioA` pode fazer com que a operação de leitura de saldo do o `UsuarioB` seja incorreta. Ou seja, enquanto o `UsuarioA` processa o saque o `UsuarioB` fez a leitura do saque e obteve o saldo R$1000,00 ao invés de R$700,00.

Para um melhor entendimento de controle de concorrência, recomendo a leitura do conceito ACID.

**Propriedades ACID**

- **Atomicidade:** A execução de uma transação deve ser atômica, ou todas as ações são executadas, ou nenhuma é;
- **Consistência:** Cada transação executada isoladamente deve preservar a consistência do banco de dados;
- **Isolamento:** Cada transação deve ser isolada dos efeitos da execução concorrente de outras transações;
- **Durabilidade:** Toda transação que for finalizada de forma bem-sucedida deve persistir seus resultados em banco mesmo na presença de falhas no sistema.

FONTE: http://www.diegomacedo.com.br/controle-de-concorrencia-em-banco-de-dados